# DB2-SQL Select Query to fetch first few records based on a field value

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ap4QO.png)
Hello,

I had a requirement to read data from 3 tables and then i have to process those records to target system. I wrote a select query as shown below to fetch data.

Table A has fields like A1,A2,A3,A4,A5

Table B has fields like B1,B2,B3

Table C has fields like C1,C2,C3

Except function is used for eliminate few records from select query result.

```
select A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,B1,B2,B3,C1,C2,C3 
  from tableA 
    left outer join tableB 
      on (tableA.A1=tableB.B1) and (tableA.A2=tableB.B2) 
    left outer join tableC 
      on (tableA.A1=tableC.C1) 
  where ORDERDATE='01/01/2019' 
Except 
select A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,B1,B2,B3,C1,C2,C3 
  from tableA 
    left outer join tableB 
      on (tableA.A1=tableB.B1) and (tableA.A2=tableB.B2) 
    left outer join tableC 
      on (tableA.A1=tableC.C1) 
  where ORDERDATE='01/01/2019' 
    and tableA.A3='Y'
```

Now this Query is working fine and return 1000 records shown below.

(or please check attachment/below link for output image in proper alignment)

[Output data for above query -Image-Attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ap4QO.png)

```
+------------+--------------+---------------+----------+------+------+------+----------+------+------+----------+
| A1 (order) | A2(Sequence) | A3(orderDate) |    A4    |  A5  |  B1  |  B2  |    B3    |  C1  |  C2  |    C3    |
+------------+--------------+---------------+----------+------+------+------+----------+------+------+----------+
| 1111       |            1 | 1/1/2019      | wqe      | 3e   | 1111 | qq   | 1/1/2019 | 1111 |    1 | 1/1/2019 |
| 1111       |            2 | 1/1/2019      | qe       | 4r   | 1111 | aa   | 1/1/2019 | 1111 |    2 | 1/1/2019 |
| 1111       |            3 | 1/1/2019      | qwe      |      | 1111 | ss   | 1/1/2019 | 1111 |    3 | 1/1/2019 |
| 2222       |            1 | 1/1/2019      |          | tg   | 2222 | cc   | 1/1/2019 | 2222 |    1 | 1/1/2019 |
| 3333       |            1 | 1/1/2019      | eqw      |      | 3333 | vv   | 1/1/2019 | 3333 |    1 | 1/1/2019 |
| 3333       |            2 | 1/1/2019      | qweq     | 5y   | 3333 | bb   | 1/1/2019 | 3333 |    2 | 1/1/2019 |
| 3333       |            3 | 1/1/2019      |          | 5u   | 3333 | nn   | 1/1/2019 | 3333 |    3 | 1/1/2019 |
| 3333       |            4 | 1/1/2019      | qwe      |      | 3333 | mm   | 1/1/2019 | 3333 |    4 | 1/1/2019 |
| 4444       |            6 | 1/1/2019      |          | 4g   | 4444 | mn   | 1/1/2019 | 4444 |    6 | 1/1/2019 |
| 9999       |            7 | 1/1/2019      | wqw      | 8m   | 9999 | yu   | 1/1/2019 | 9999 |    7 | 1/1/2019 |
+------------+--------------+---------------+----------+------+------+------+----------+------+------+----------+
```

but i want to modify my select query to fetch all records for one order at a time. so that i will process those records and change status for those records.then next time when i run query it will fetch records for next Order '2222' and so on..

So from above example: if i run select query, i have to get records for Order 1111 (first 3 records) only.

Thank you.

Comment: the sample data isn't showing this but does your data have multiple A2(Sequence) for A1 (order)

Comment: Question: Why the `EXCEPT`?  Why not just `SELECT ... WHERE tableA.A3 <> 'Y'`?  There's ways to do this (probably best done with a data-change-table), but _why_?

Comment: Hi Experts, Please suggest how to modify my SELECT query to achieve the above requirement. Thank you. YQ

Comment: Why do you want to process the orders one at a time? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: It seems you are trying to shorten your query somewhat because the SQL provided will not produce the output shown. Problems are A2 does not equal B2, and there are multiple rows in tableC that match up with A1 in tableA. We really can't help if you aren't going to give us what is really happening.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `RANK` function from [OLAP specifications](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_74/db2/rbafzolapexp.htm).

```
WITH A AS
(
-- Your original query
select A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,B1,B2,B3,C1,C2,C3 
  from tableA 
    left outer join tableB 
      on (tableA.A1=tableB.B1) and (tableA.A2=tableB.B2) 
    left outer join tableC 
      on (tableA.A1=tableC.C1) 
  where ORDERDATE='01/01/2019' 
Except 
select A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,B1,B2,B3,C1,C2,C3 
  from tableA 
    left outer join tableB 
      on (tableA.A1=tableB.B1) and (tableA.A2=tableB.B2) 
    left outer join tableC 
      on (tableA.A1=tableC.C1) 
  where ORDERDATE='01/01/2019' 
    and tableA.A3='Y'
-- End of your original query
)
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT A.*, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY A1) RK_
FROM A
)
WHERE RK_=1;
```

Your query must not return already processed orders of course.